# Rails under test: database configuration does not specify adapter production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

rails 3.2.18
mysql2 0.3.18

try to start `rspec spec`
got many of:

```
19) Reports::TaxReportService  should properly generate for rests
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified:
       database configuration does not specify adapter
     # /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection'
     # /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
     # /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
     # /home/drobazko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
     # ./spec/support/database_cleaner.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

***database.yml**:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
# 
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mrdelivery_development
  pool: 5
  username: hd_user
  password: 
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mrdelivery_test
  pool: 5
  username: hd_user
  password: 
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mrdelivery_production
  pool: 5
  username: hd_user
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

In development everything works fine.

Comment: post your **entire** database.yml

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

Rails environment is case sensitive. Either it is 'Test' in database.yml or you are running tests as "RAILS_ENV=Test"

Comment: in database,yml `test` is lower-cased. I tried `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec` no result

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

This will setup your test database required for running test cases.